# How can I extract exactly the "sends" I view in tracking tab on Email Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, email-tracking, tracking-extract

I've been really struggling trying to extract the table view "My Tracking" in Tracking, on Email Studio.

I want to have the information displayed as I see in the Tracking tab. How can I export this table without having to copy, paste and format it on my sheets?

I blurred the data, but here it is the table I'm trying to extract:
[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the standard reports: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_email_performance_over_time_report.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_recent_email_sending_summary_report.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good workaround for this is to:

1. Select all the emails you wish to report on using the checkboxes on the left (or just select all of the emails on the page).
2. Click on 'Compare Email Sends'
3. Click on 'Export'

You'll now have a .csv file with the information as displayed in Tracking > Sends.